# xPath, XSLT. Get max by attribute in another nodeset

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have:

```
<Data>
  <DocumentCodebook>
    <C4505>
      <Item Value="1" ABSpriority="1" />
      <Item Value="2" ABSpriority="4" />
      <Item Value="3" ABSpriority="2" />
      <Item Value="4" ABSpriority="3"/>
    </C4505>
  <DocumentCodebook>
  <ApplicationData>
     <SelectedInsurance>
        <Insurance ProductId="2"/>
        <Insurance ProductId="3"/>
        <Insurance ProductId="1"/>
     </SelectedInsurance>
  </ApplicationData>
 </Data>
```

I need to get **Data/ApplicationData/SelectedInsurance/Insurance/@ProductId** which have the highest **@ABSpriority** in C4505. @Value is similiar @ProductId.

For this xml result is "2". Because ProductId="2" have the highest ABSPriority="4" (More than ProductId=1 and 3).

**Example 2**

```
<Data>
  <DocumentCodebook>
    <C4505>
      <Item Value="1" ABSpriority="1" />
      <Item Value="2" ABSpriority="4" />
      <Item Value="3" ABSpriority="2" />
      <Item Value="4" ABSpriority="3"/>
    </C4505>
  <DocumentCodebook>
  <ApplicationData>
     <SelectedInsurance>
        <Insurance ProductId="1"/>
        <Insurance ProductId="4"/>
     </SelectedInsurance>
  </ApplicationData>
 </Data>
```

Result is "4".  ProductId="4" have the highest ABSPriority="3".

Comment: Please share the output on how exactly you want the result be like

Comment: I need to write result in xsl:element.  In this example result is "2". (For @ProductId="2" @ABSpriority="4")

Comment: My question was: What actually do you want get as a result ? Not where you want to write. (It's not clear from your description.) **1** Please share how did you try to solve this problem ? **2** Show the sample output you need to generate.

Comment: Sorry, my English is too bad. As result I need @ProductId in Data/ApplicationData/SelectedInsurance/Insurance which have the highest @ABSpriority. I tried `/Data/DocumentCodebook/C4505/Item[@ABSpriority=max(/Data/DocumentCodebook/C4505/Item[boolean(string(/Data/ApplicationData/SelectedInsurance/Insurance[@ProductId=current()/@Value]/ProductId))]/@ABSpriority)]@Value` but it looks dumb

Comment: @RodionGataullin Please don't post code in comments - edit you question instead. I think you also need a better example, because I don't see more than one of anything, so it's not clear what you mean by max.

Comment: I have edited question

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Yes, it supports XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be using **[keys](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key)** to resolve cross-references.

Now, since we are told that XSLT 2.0 offers no special advantage here, I would revert to a more primitive method using XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="item" match="Item" use="@Value" />

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="ApplicationData/SelectedInsurance/Insurance">
            <xsl:sort select="key('item', @ProductId)/@ABSpriority" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="@ProductId"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this assumes there will be only one `Insurance` with the maximum `ABSpriority`. In case of a tie, only the first one in document order will be returned.

Comment: Yeah, thank you! It works. I didn't know about keys.

Answer (score 0):

Given a node sequence S, to find the node that has the highest value for some quantity Q, the "crude" way to do it is

```
<xsl:variable name="max" selecy="max(S / Q)"/>
<xsl:for-each select="S[Q = $max]">...</xsl:for-each>
```

That's not very elegant because it involves processing S twice. Saxon has a higher-order function saxon:highest() that does it in once step, but that involves extensions (and higher-order functions), so it only works in the commercial versions of the product.

The other way to do it in a single pass is with recursion.

```
<xsl:function name="f:highest">
  <xsl:param name="input" as="node()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="max-so-far"/>
  <xsl:param name="top-nodes"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="empty($input)">
      <xsl:sequence select="$top-nodes"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="Q($input[1]) = $max-so-far">
      <xsl:sequence select="f:highest(remove($input, 1), $max-so-far, ($top-nodes, $input[1])"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="Q($input[1]) > $max-so-far">
      <xsl:sequence select="f:highest(remove($input, 1), Q($input[1]), $input[1]"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:sequence select="f:highest(remove($input, 1), $max-so-far, $top-nodes"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:function>
```

Here Q(node) represents whatever expression you are evaluating on a node to get the value of interest, e.g. `number($node/@ABSPriority)`.

In XSLT 3.0 you could replace the recursive function with an equivalent xsl:iterate loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do this. Result in **Insurance_Type** element.

```
<xsl:variable name="ProductList">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Data/ApplicationData/SelectedInsurance/Insurance">
        <xsl:if test="position()!=1">
            <!--<xsl:value-of select=","/>-->
            <xsl:value-of select="&quot;,&quot;" />
        </xsl:if>
        <!--<xsl:value-of select="@ProductId"/>-->
        <xsl:value-of select="@ProductId" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="MaxABS" select="max(/Data/DocumentCodebook/C4505/Item[contains($ProductList,@Value)]/@ABSpriority)" />
<xsl:element name="Types">
    <xsl:element name="Insurance_Type">
        <xsl:value-of select="/Data/DocumentCodebook/C4505/Item[@ABSpriority=$MaxABS]/@Value" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```